# SEO implications of moving a section of site to a subdomain - Drupal to Jekyll/Wordpress migration

Tags: seo, wordpress, migration, jekyll

We are strongly considering moving significant, relatively static, portions of our existing Drupal site (`yinyanghouse.com`) out of Drupal and into a subdomain built up with a static site generator like Jekyll.

This section would be something like 900 pages or so of largely static content with no need for comments, etc. (although keeping Adsense would be important) - something like `resources.yinyanghouse.com`.

Then we are more than likely going to move the dynamic/community portions of our site into Wordpress for easier upgrade paths and better adherence to API's between versions (in our opinion) than Drupal.

My question, then, is will there be any significant ramifications of moving a page such as:

`http://www.yinyanghouse.com/acupuncturepoints/lv3` to `resources.yinyanghouse.com/acupuncturepoints/lv3`?

Any things to watch out for or are just 301's and fixing all our internal links enough?

Any experiences with Jekyll and larger sites? What about hosting that many pages on Github pages vs. locally with Nginx?

These are crucial pages of our rankings overall and we really don't want to lose that but moving them to a static site generator will help us greatly with maintenance and hosting costs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine if you use 301 redirects and update all the internal links.

Several years ago, I moved my most popular page to its own sub-domain and then expanded it into an entire mini-site on that sub-domain.  During that process, it continued to receive search engine referrals uninterrupted.

Answer (score -1):

I hope everything here is done on a VPS. Shared hosting for such large movement will not be so helpful.

Yes, SEO will get affected if you perform this kinda of change because Jekyll and Wordpress are both different CMS and user friendly but they both treat and design your content in their pages a bit different than drupal. This sudden change might get you a bit difference in SEO but that will be a small bump in the road.

Although this sounds interesting but I am not sure of how you are gonna handle the dynamic and static part together if required. Instead of going with two different CMS, I suggest you use cache with drupal and reverse proxy the static content with nginx. This will hugely save you with a lot of hosting money and make your server a happy place to live for your website.

Varnish cache is supported by Drupal in their latest update I guess. If not then you can still use it with a simple settings.

Comment: We already have drupal heavily cached by the fine folks at omega8.cc hosting.  The problem is that we really want to move away from drupal entirely because of version to version upgrade difficulties.  As large parts of our site are really resource pages that never change but are heavily linked to putting them into a ssg like jekyll makes sense.  The only problem in my mind behind SEO is cosmetic, that is managing two separate themes...  Consider this would be a "resources" section that doesn't seem to hard.